# What are tax-derived finances?

Tags: collocation

Maybe this is not a question relating to the usage of the English language. I struggle to find the explanation of "tax-derived finances".

Here is the context:
"The principal reasons for this are that rich children stay longer in school, that a year in a university is disproportionately more expensive than a year in high school, and that most private universities depend—at least indirectly—on tax- derived finances"

My guess is that it is the money exempt from being taxed by the government.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

full text here:  [GRE Prep Course with Software 2003](https://books.google.com/books?id=DVBmZ8wMO2oC&lpg=PA337&ots=fzQglLgcEE&dq=%22The%20principal%20reasons%20for%20this%20are%20that%20rich%20children%20stay%20longer%20in%20school%2C%20that%20a%20year%20in%20a%20university%20is%20disproportionately%20more%20expensive%20than%20a&pg=PA337#v=onepage&q=%22The%20principal%20reasons%20for%20this%20are%20that%20rich%20children%20stay%20longer%20in%20school,%20that%20a%20year%20in%20a%20university%20is%20disproportionately%20more%20expensive%20than%20a&f=false)

This is a  discussion of the financing higher education which depends in part on government funding.  **Tax-derived**:  it comes from the taxpayers.